# Excel VBA: How do I auto shift cells down when new data is inserted automatically?

Tags: excel, vba

To start off, I am new to using VB in excel. Here is my issue: I am using DreamReport to send out plant data to an excel file every 24 hours. I am using a single, static excel file.

The problem is that by using a static file, the data is replaced every day. This is because the data is automatically placed in the same group of cells, and the previous 24 hours get overwritten. Here is how the data is placed:

[image: Excel Sheet]

So, I need a script that will shift the new data, and all of the prior data down, immediately after the report adds the data from the screenshot, so that no data is overwritten.

Thanks in advance for anyone that helps! Please ask questions if I was not clear about anything.

Comment: Before comments come in that you should [show us your attempts](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), I want to say that you shouldn't upload your example as an external link - many people dont trust links and just wont click on them. For me a firewall totally blocks it anyways, so

Comment: I explained my issue thoroughly though? I also said I was new to VB. I just need help.

Comment: I'm sorry @DylanThompson but you have not provided a [mcve] which is typically necessary to really isolate your issue.  Consider reading [ask] and [edit] your attempt so far, and what specifically isn't working within the question itself.

Comment: How would you like me to give an example of something that I have no idea how to do?

Comment: The reason I posted was to learn how to do this.

Comment: It's important to know that SO is a site where people help others with existing code, so please browse for a starting point and come back with specific questions.  

["We all have jobs to do. Even when it seems like our task is too hard or we don’t know where to start, it is always worth the effort to at least try. Asking others to do our work for us can also be seen as rude. If we try for ourselves, we may succeed. When we have no idea where to start, we must search and research our problem before asking for help."](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt)

Comment: So everyone just assumes that I didn't try to figure it out myself first? I understand what you're saying but I did try to find an existing code for what I wanted. I could not find a solution, and know nothing about coding in excel. So I made a post here. You may have noticed that someone realized this and is working on helping me at the moment.

Comment: Page 79 says that you can set the exported files to have the date in their filename. If you're set on using excel then it wouldn't be too hard to have a macro loop through those files and gather the data into one sheet - https://www.logic-control.com/datasheets/78/Dream_Report_User_Manual.pdf

Answer (score -1):

As what I gather from what you have written and the screenshot the excel sheet gets fed the Rows 3 and 4 ( or maybe only row 3) by your other application-DreamReport. So with the given information you can paste the following code on the Sheet1(Sheet1) in the VBA editor of the Excel workbook.
What happens now is everytime data is fed that data shifts down creating an empty range for next days data.

Press Alt+F11 to open VBA editor then double click the below sheet as in the picture. Once opened paste the below code. Then test and confirm.
[Double click this sheet to paste the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DahDa.jpg)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("A3:C4")         ' Checks whether this range changed

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False      ' disables events to avoid a loop
    Range("A3:C4").Insert Shift:=xlDown   ' shifts this range down
    Application.EnableEvents = True       ' ensures events are re-enabled

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you this seems like what I am looking for. I should have mentioned however that DreamReport is feeding all of the rows, in other words, there is no user input. So, would I just have to change the range to all of the cells?

Comment: Good point, That's the next tricky part. Is there a way for you to confirm which cell record DeamReport feeds to the excel last.... Because the moment one cell in the Keycells changes the macro gets activated and we don't want DreamReport to have halfway pasted data when that happens. Otherwise we can leave this be a manual macro with a button for you.

Comment: So, the first code you provided only works when I manually change a value in the cell. Otherwise, it just acts as before and replaces the data set. Now, is this even possible to do, considering the excel file is intended to never need opened?

Comment: I presume so, as per my knowledge MS Excel workbook needs to be kept open for events to run. Can you run a test feeding Dreamreport to the closed book? If so I'm afraid MS Excel may not be the best solution. we can try Google Sheets.

Comment: Running it to the closed book just replaces the data. Running it while it is open does not change anything. Maybe DreamReport is the problem? Let me know if you have any sort of work around or ideas.

Comment: Hmm, Sorry without understanding how the data is feed to the excel sheet with Dreamreports I cannot think of a way.